# deleting node from a singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, reference, singly-linked-list

I have a simple function that searches for a node with a given key from a single linked list and deletes it.
The function works when the node with that holds the given key is everywhere except if that node is the head of the list.
Why does this happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void printlist(struct Node* node){
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list 
   and a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in linked list */
void deleteNode(struct Node* head, int key){
    if(head->data==key){
        head = head->next;
    }
    else {
        while(head->next->data!=key){
            head = head->next;
        }
        head->next = head->next->next;
    }
}

int main(){

    struct Node* first = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->data = 1;
    second->data = 2;
    third->data = 3;
    first->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next = NULL;

    printlist(first); // prints 123

    deleteNode(first, 2);  
    printlist(first); // prints 13

    deleteNode(first, 1);
    printlist(first); // still prints 13
}
```

Comment: What do you think `first` points to after the second call to `deleteNode`? Clue: What do you think it points to after the first call to `deleteNode`?

Comment: while the comment of your function is correct, the prototype does not correspond, you are not sending a pointer to a pointer ;) try making it work while sending ```&first``` instead of just ```first```

Comment: @Angevil - I was typing my answer as you were typing your comment. Maybe I've done too much?  Let's see what the OP feels.

Comment: @Adrian I'm used to teach C, so I prefer giving clues over solutions ^=^

Comment: I also work in a teaching/learning environment. But, sometimes, a broader 'clue' can be helpful: teach by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call this function: `void deleteNode(struct Node* head, int key)` with a first argument that is a pointer to a `Node` struct (as you do twice in your `main`), then what the function receives as its first argument is ***a copy of the pointer you gave***!

You probably know that a function: `void Increment(int n)` can do whatever it likes to the `n` it's passed, without changing the variable in the calling module. So, if you want the function to actually change the value in the calling block, you give it a pointer:

```
void Increment(int* n) {
    ++(*n);
}
```

Likewise, if you want a function to change a pointer, then you have to pass it a ***pointer to that pointer***. Try this:

```
void deleteNode(struct Node** head, int key){
    Node* temp = *head;
    if(temp->data==key){
        *head = temp->next; // Only need to change *head if its the first one ...
    }
    else {
        while(temp->next->data!=key){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = temp->next->next; // ... else we have already changed the actual "links"
    }
}
```

And, in `main`, use:

```
deleteNode(&first, 2);
```

and:

```
deleteNode(&first, 1);
```

Let us know what happens.

*Note: Incidentally, this is not "best possible code" - by removing a link without actually deleting the object pointed to, you are creating a memory leak.*

*Note 2: Also, if the `key` is not found, your code will "fall off" the end of the list, when it finds a NULL `next` pointer!*

Answer (score 2):

The function deals with a copy of the original head. So changing of the copy does not influence on the original node. You should either pass the head node by reference through pointer or return from the function the changed head node. Also you have to check in the beginning of the function whether the head node is equal to NULL. Otherwise the function can invoke undefined behavior.

For example

```
void deleteNode( struct Node **head, int key )
{
    while( *head != NULL && ( *head )->data != key ) head = &( *head )->next;

    if ( *head != NULL ) *head = ( *head )->next;
}
```

And call it like

```
deleteNode( &first, 1 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void printlist(struct Node* node){
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list 
   and a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in linked list */
void deleteNode( struct Node **head, int key )
{
    while( *head != NULL && ( *head )->data != key ) head = &( *head )->next;

    if ( *head != NULL ) *head = ( *head )->next;
}

int main(){

    struct Node* first = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->data = 1;
    second->data = 2;
    third->data = 3;
    first->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next = NULL;

    printlist(first); // prints 123

    deleteNode(&first, 2);  
    printlist(first); // prints 13

    deleteNode(&first, 1);
    printlist(first); // still prints 13
}
```

Its output is

```
123
13
3
```

Or

```
struct Node * deleteNode( struct Node *head, int key )
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        if ( head->data == key )
        {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else 
        {
            struct Node *current = head;
            while( current->next != NULL && current->next->data != key )
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
            if ( current->next != NULL ) current->next = current->next->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

and call it like

```
first = deleteNode( first, 1 );
```

Here is another demonstrative program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void printlist(struct Node* node){
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list 
   and a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in linked list */
    struct Node * deleteNode( struct Node *head, int key )
    {
        if ( head != NULL )
        {
            if ( head->data == key )
            {
                head = head->next;
            }
            else 
            {
                struct Node *current = head;
                while( current->next != NULL && current->next->data != key )
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                if ( current->next != NULL ) current->next = current->next->next;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }

int main(){

    struct Node* first = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->data = 1;
    second->data = 2;
    third->data = 3;
    first->next = second;
    second->next = third;
    third->next = NULL;

    printlist(first); // prints 123

    first = deleteNode(first, 2);  
    printlist(first); // prints 13

    first = deleteNode(first, 1);
    printlist(first); // still prints 13
}
```

Again its output is

```
123
13
3
```

In general nodes of lists are allocated dynamically. So the function that deletes nodes should also free the deleted node or return it from the function.

Comment: Near simultaneous answers happen all the time, @Adrian.  It’s inevitable.  Don’t fret. Just make sure yours is as good as it can be, and wait.  If yours is still, there’s a fair chance it’ll be selected.  No-one is obliged to delete their own independent answer simply because it covers the same ground as another.  It usually means that both answers are mostly correct.  Relax!